# Путь до папке в папке с проектом C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно узнать, как использовать папку где находится проект (если к примеру я его перемещу). Мне нужно для ListBox. В данный момент код выглядит так:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"/docs");
        FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
        foreach (FileInfo filenames in files)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(filenames);
        }
```

Как мне использовать путь где находится сам файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location; // путь, включая .exe
```

или

```
var location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // базовая директория
```

Comment: Как мне объявить его как переменную?

Comment: @Snegan, обновил пост

Comment: Всё, я сделал через string, всё норм!